# How can I draw a curve between two points in ARKit with Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I'm developing an app that helps in throwing paper waste in dustbin.

How do I draw a curve between two points in AR world?

I'm using Xcode and ARKit. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: See the image below, the curve shown in white dotted line is what I want to achieve in ar[image: A brief demo of what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with ARKit, it is a pure SceneKit question. You need to apply [Physics Simulation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/physics_simulation) to the paper ball you are throwing.

You then use the function `applyForce(_:asImpulse:)` to throw the ball. The curve will be a result of the force applied and gravity of the scene.

The ball will have a `SCNPhysicsBodyType.dynamic` and the rest of the scene can have `SCNPhysicsBodyType.static` as they don't move (floor, bin , desk, etc...).

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to AR in iOS, so its a SceneKit question. I have to detect the real world paper ball and show the guidance curve to dustbin just like the while dotted guide curve in Angry Birds AR game. How can i solve it?

Comment: oh sorry I didn't realise the paper ball was a real one! in that case, look at `SCNShape` that you can create from a bezier path. how you calculate the curve though, that sounds like pure math depending on distance, weight of the ball, force...wind from the desktop fan from your colleague...

Comment: can we use the bezier path's addcurve method to add the hyperbola typed curve?

Comment: what have you actually tried so far? show your efforts / code.